# How to convert Math.max or Math.min into pseudocode?

Tags: math, pseudocode

I need to convert this to pseudocode. But I don't know what to do with math.min, math.max and math.sqrt.

```
function intersect(sphere, box) 
  float x = Math.max(box.minX, Math.min(sphere.x, box.maxX))
  float y = Math.max(box.minY, Math.min(sphere.y, box.maxY))
  float z = Math.max(box.minZ, Math.min(sphere.z, box.maxZ))


  float distance = Math.sqrt((x - sphere.x) * (x - sphere.x) +
                           (y - sphere.y) * (y - sphere.y) +
                           (z - sphere.z) * (z - sphere.z))

  return distance < sphere.radius
end function
```

Comment: Just drop the `Math.`? And maybe declare the return type of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Andrew Morton:
.Math